# Knitr Old Bug return?

Tags: r, knitr

I have updated my os debian stable to debian testing, also i update Texlive to Texlive 2013.
When I will recompute a 3 day ago code in Knitr which will not have any problem 3day ago i  have this error today :

```
! Package color Error: Argument `969' not in range [0,1].
```

It's like hier : https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/308

But i'm not using coma as dec separator in R or Knitr ?

And I don't know if it's binding but all my pdf's figure are blank now ?

Ps I use :

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
knitr_1.5
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
```

As ask by @Yihui this is an Ecm

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
\begin{document} 
    <<createdata,echo=TRUE>>= #fond de carte 
        library (OpenStreetMap) 
        data = c(1:100) 
    @ 
\end{document}
```

My /usr/share/i18n/locales/fr_FR file is like this :

```
LC_NUMERIC
decimal_point             "<U002C>"
thousands_sep             "<U0020>"
grouping                  3
END LC_NUMERIC
```

Comment: To precise I use the locale : "fr_FR.UTF-8"

Comment: That sounds odd. Perhaps you set `options(OutDec = ',')` somewhere? Anyway, please check if the latest version on Github works: https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme Regarding the blank figures, I need a reproducible example, unless you used the Cairo devices (Cairo 1.5-3 on CRAN is buggy).

Comment: @Yihui This ECM don't work :
   `\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
     \geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
    \begin{document}
    <<createdata,echo=TRUE>>=
      #fond de carte
         library (OpenStreetMap)
    data = c(1:100)
    @
    \end{document}`

I think the problem come from `OpenStreetMap` ? whithout the code run successfully.

Comment: Can you edit your own post and add the example? The comment is not an appropriate place to write examples that contain line breaks.

Comment: @Yihui done can you repeat the bug ? and Merry christmas

Comment: Can you try the development version? https://github.com/yihui/knitr

Comment: I have make my test with the development version since your first comment. Sorry I don't have precise that

Comment: I recompile the git source today and retest :
The preambule is Ok
but in document I have this :
    \begin{knitrout}
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0,969, 0,969, 0,969}\color{fgcolor}

Comment: Sounds like a bug of R. What does this return in your R console? `options(OutDec = '.'); sprintf('%s', 0.969)`

Comment: this > `options(OutDec = '.'); sprintf('%s', 0.969)` : [1] "0.969"

Comment: That is odd. Can you put `sessionInfo()` in your .Rnw document, and see what is the output in the .tex file?

Answer (score 0):

@Yihui in the last comment :
`sessionInfo()` give this in the .tex file :

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0,969, 0,969, 0,969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{verbatim}
## R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## 
## locale:
## [1] fr_FR.UTF-8
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
##  [1] vegan_2.0-7         permute_0.7-0       MASS_7.3-29        
##  [4] maptools_0.8-27     OpenStreetMap_0.3.1 raster_2.1-66          
##  [7] rJava_0.9-4         rgdal_0.8-12        sp_1.0-14          
## [10] xtable_1.7-1        hierfstat_0.04-10   gtools_3.1.1       
## [13] adegenet_1.3-9.2    ade4_1.6-2          knitr_1.5.15       
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] ape_3.0-11      evaluate_0.5.1  foreign_0.8-57  formatR_0.10   
##  [5] grid_3.0.2      igraph_0.6.6    lattice_0.20-24 nlme_3.1-113   
##  [9] stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.0.2
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}
```

in this chunk code :

```
<<geo1, echo=FALSE,out.height="0.45\\textheight",fig.show='hold'>>=
sessionInfo()
@
```